# How can I get the mappings from feeds

Tags: 7, feeds

I want to get programmatically the mapping which was set by the user on the feeds config page (`/admin/structure/feeds/<name>/mapping_en`). But how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fount a working solution:

```
$f = feeds_importer('your-importer-machine-name');
$m = $f->processor->getMappings(); // This returns the mapping.
```

It's just needed one day to find it...